# How to attach div to bottom without absolute?

Tags: html, css

So I have a footer:

```
<div id="footer" >
    <div style="padding:20px;">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

Which is in wrapper with style :

```css
#page { width:964px; margin:0 auto; }
```

So I need that the footer div would be attached to the bottom of the browser. The problem is if I adding:

```css
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```

Some of the previous div intersects with footer and also i need to set height and width by my self.

[image: demo]

Comment: You have the `#footer` inside the `#page` but you want it at the very bottom of your HTML document, is that it?

Comment: Yes, because if it would be outside the #page, i need twice to write same properties. I think it is not good... But may be i am wrong...

Comment: Can't you provide a link or post more information about the HTML markup and any relevant CSS, specially for the `#page` and the `div` that intersects the `#footer`?

Comment: all code is here. Nothing else is there.

Answer (score 7):

Try like this..

**The CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

**The HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>wrapper text here</p>    
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    <p>footer text here.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this support responsive height? What if content has long paragraph and suppose to push down the container's height automatically.

Comment: This is the only technique that worked for me.  The only downside that I can see is having to specify the footer height twice, but not a huge issue if you're using a css generator or templating system.  See http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ for more info.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/ttQAz/) is  not exactly what you ask for, but it is a similar implementation I did using `position: fixed`.

For what you are trying to achieve you will need to use `position: absolute` to make it happen. And then you will have to give out the height of the element manually for it to fit properly. And when you have content inside the `footer`, you can use `padding` to perfect the shape.

These are the only options possible. Either go for a `fixed` positioning or `absolute` positioning.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```css
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Here's a good [article](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) to understand how `position:` works

Comment: but now appears the scroll if more information in body exists... May be in the first post i described the problem not correctly, because i need if in the body are not much posts, it need to be at the bottom of browser, but if there is some more of it, this need to be in the end, but also stick to the browser (i have some pixels between div and browser line in default).

Comment: This isn't at all the right solution. You'll need to use something called a "sticky footer". See here for one good solution: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer

Comment: he asked how to attach an element to the bottom of the browser viewport and position: fixed does exactly this. If he wanted a "sticky footer", as you are supposing, it's not in the question.

Comment: Nothing happens... May be it is because of *{
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0; 
 outline: 0;
}

Comment: that won't affect it, but I suggest you to try Tom's link if that's the same result you are after

Comment: This places the footer over-top content (hugging bottom of browser) when the page extends past the height of the browser.

Comment: @Gaʀʀʏ true, but that is the expected behaviour because positioned elements are taken off the DOM flow - meaning that they don't take 'space' like elements with position 'static' (the default); it is common practice to set some `margin-bottom` or `padding-bottom` on a wrapper to avoid content being 'behind' the footer - to a value at least equal if not greater than the footer height.